# SQL two selects not sure how to combine

Tags: sql, select, dbase

I am trying to combine the following two sql statement so I get everything in one return.  I am not sure of the best way to do this.  The issue is the IPMS data and value

Issues was Resolved by using identifiers

ID2.Data as Data2

Then using multiple joins

using the IDs

Comment: You want Client, CSDESC, Matter, and Matter Description for both the first query and the second query in the same result set? You wanted them in separate records or the same record; not sure what your data looks like?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well.  Yes I would like them in one result.

Comment: The result would have a header that looked like this   CLIENT, CSDESC, MATTER, MDESC.  I could not figure out how to join or union the data together and get the correct results